# Linking Google Script Variable to the Javascript in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3, google-apps-script

So I feel I'm almost there to the solution but I'm really in need of help here. What I'm trying to do is to create an array using .getValues() to get a range that contains four columns (Name, Address, Latitude, and Longitude). After that I want to return the variable back into a global variable and then call that variable from the HTML side. I tried linking the google script with the HTML and then calling the variable there but having quite a bit of trouble with that. Thank you guys for all of your help!

Below is the google script:

```
 var id = 'Spreadsheet Key';

 function doGet(e) {
 var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Sample');

   return html.evaluate().setTitle('Directory Map');
 }

 function entries() {
 var blop = 
  SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('A1:D').getValues();
  return blop;
 }
```

This is the HTML in Google Script.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
     function initAutocomplete() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 39.8283, lng: -98.5795},
          zoom: 5,
          mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
          gestureHandling: 'greedy'
        });

        var locations = [blop];

        for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
          var sites = locations[i];
          var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(sites[2],sites[3]);
          var sites = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            title: sites[0],
          });
        };
     }

    </script>
    <script>  google.script.run.entries(); </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyAPIKey&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"async defer></script>
    <script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="SampleCode.gs"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The starting point is:

```
<script>  google.script.run.entries(); </script>
```

The above code runs when the page is loaded in the browser.  You need a "success handler", and then the success handler can store the data somewhere.  You could put the data into a window variable, or local browser storage.

```
<script>
  window.storeSheetValues = function(theReturnedData) {
    console.log('theReturnedData: ' + theReturnedData)
    console.log('typeof theReturnedData: ' + typeof theReturnedData)

    window.mySheetData = theReturnedData;//Put the data into a window variable
  }

  google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(storeSheetValues)
    .entries(); 

</script>
```

Check the data type of the return value coming back from the server.  If it's a string, you may want to turn it back into an array.